# How do I intercept a form's values before sending it?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, beanstream

I currently have a large form that gets sent to our payment authorizer (done so by action="paymentautherizerURL" ), however I am not getting all of the information I require back from them when I go to store the transaction in my DB.

I either need to intercept the form data before it submits so that I can store it in the session (we are using PHP / jQuery), or I have also tried sending it to an intermediary scriptlet that grabs the information I need, and then using jQuery's $.post() to re-build and send off the data to the authorizer.

the second approach does not seem to work, however, at least to the best of my efforts. I'm not sure that a $.post properly emulates the form's send action, or at least I have not done it right.

```
<?php
session_start();

$post = $_POST;

//gets all of the information that beanstream does not return to approved.php, but is still required to make
//a legitimate database entry. gets from the POST and stores in the session array for approved.PHP to access

$_SESSION['approvedArray']['billAddress'] = $_POST['ordAddress1'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['billProvince'] = $_POST['ordProvince'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['billCountry'] = $_POST['ordCountry'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['billPostalCode'] = $_POST['ordPostalCode'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['billCity'] = $_POST['ordCity'];

$_SESSION['approvedArray']['shipAddress'] = $_POST['shipAddress1'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['shipPostal'] = $_POST['shipPostalCode'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['shipCity'] = $_POST['shipCity'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['shipProvince'] = $_POST['shipProvince'];
$_SESSION['approvedArray']['shipCountry'] = $_POST['shipCountry'];

session_write_close();
//the javascript below will send what is required to beanstream as though it were sent from the form

<script type='text/javascript'>
$.post(, {
    <?php
    //rebuild the POST such that "name: value, " except the last name/value will not be followed by a comma
    $keys = array_keys($_POST);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST); $i++) {
        $currentKey = $keys[$i];
        $currentPost = $_POST[i];
        echo $currentKey . ": " . $currentPost;
        if ($i < (count($_POST) - 1)) {
            echo ", ";
        }
    }
    ?>
});
</script> 

?>
```

normally, the transaction authorizer will re-direct the user to one of 3 pages (approved, declined, error), and our website does the job from there. however, it's currently stuck at this page, which makes me think it's not sending off properly.

i'm open to all forms of criticism, approaches and ideas. thanks very much in advance, and if any other information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: you can handle the data before sending it

Comment: Yeah, what @lbu said.  Basic client-side input validation using the onsubmit callback.  This is web development 101.

Comment: Ibu: that is the purpose of this scriptlet. it is receiving a large amount of form data in the POST, handling what it requires, and then re-sending to its actual destination.

Comment: dossy: i forgot about onsubmit= . would this be an appropriate place to run this scriptlet but without the jQuery re-direct? thanks.

Comment: Wait, you started _another_ `<?php` tag before you closed the first one?

Comment: THANK you mc10. what a juvenile error...you were the second pair of eyes that I required. this scriptlet works just as expected now. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing the form tag to include an onSubmit attribute:

```
<form action="notmal_action.whatever" onSubmit="return save_data_function()">
```

Where the save_data_function reads the values from the form and sends it to a script on your server to save in a database (or where ever). I use hidden iframes to make this request hidden from the user...

```
<script>
function save_data_function() {
$('#iframe_id').attr('src', 'data_saving_script.extension?data_1=' + $('form_data_1').val().serialize() + '&data_2=' + $('form_data_2').val().serialize());
}
</script>
```

You can set a timeout if the data isn't being passed quick enough to the "data_saving_script.extension" file.

Answer (score 2):

Since your existing example already has a dependency on javascript, you could move to saving the data with AJAX and then using a traditional submit to do the "real" POST to the payment gateway.

Assuming that your form has `id="foo"`, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
$('form#foo').submit(function(event, doRealSubmit) {
    // this executes on the second pass
    if (doRealSubmit) {
        // returning true gets browser to do a real submit
        return true; 
    }

    // this executes on the first pass
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url/to/post/to/your/server',
        type: 'POST',
        // this serializes the form data in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // trigger 'submit' event again, but pass the doRealSubmit flag
            $('form#foo').trigger('submit', [true]);
        }
    });

    // returning false prevents browser from processing the real submit
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Also, you may want to build the `data` attribute manually, so that you include only the fields you actually want to process. If you avoid sending the sensitive values (like credit card number) to your own server, it saves you some security concerns and liabilities.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `action="paymentautherizerURL"` you should send it to your own page:

```
<form action='process.php' method='post'>
```

now in your process.php you can work with the data (validation, filtering ..)

and when you are done you can send the data to the right place using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

With curl you can send post data and wait for the response to decide which page to show.

Comment: thanks Ibu. currently, the action is actually set to this scriptlet, not the payment authorizer, sorry, I think i obfuscated my question a bit up there.

Comment: you dont need to send an extra form with jquery, just send it once to your script and work with the data. so what is not working with your code exactly

Comment: if the POST was sent properly to the authorizer, it will re-direct back to the appropriate page based off of the returned data. currently, there is no response, so it is not sending to the authorizer properly. how would I send the POST using cURL instead of $.post? I think using $.post is the problem as I don't think it's actually re-directing the page

Comment: dont use $.post() simply validate your form then let the submit button do its default action. and for debugging, on the process.php, do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see if you are properly sending the data

Comment: i'm sorry, you seem to misunderstand...the validation occurs far before anything i've mentioned here. I am just trying to get some of the form input before it's sent off to the authorizer, so i'm using this intermediary scriptlet

Answer (score 0):

No need to put the data in sessions, on submit of form called a validate function in which done all the validation  and then post the data to  ur process.php using ajex , then it will retain on that page...

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the data in the session - it's the wrong place to keep transactional data.

Post the stuff to a script you host, write **only** the stuff you need to keep to your database, generate an order reference for it,

then....

if you are using a payment processor (e.g. Paypal)

redirect to a second script passing the order reference in the URL. On the second script put in a form with hidden fields cotaining **only** the details required by your payment processor and some javascript to submiot the form automatically and a message to the user like 'Connecting to Paypal...'

If you are using merchant services to authorize the payment

before you generate output from the landing script, send the details to your authorizer using (e.g.) curl and parse the response, record the response against the order in the database and output a suitable message to the customer via the web page